# dart/flutter find value of another key based on key value from same set of records

Tags: flutter, dart

I am modifying the whole question to simplify what I am looking for.

for example this is the list.

```
List animals = [{'name': 'horse', 'color': 'black'}, {'name': 'dog', 'color': 'white'}];
```

now say I have the name horse and I want the value of color for horse.

update:

```
List animals = [{'name': 'horse','attributes':{'eyecolor':'green', 'color': 'black'}}, {'name': 'dog', 'attributes':{'eyecolor':'red' ,'color': 'white'}}];
```

I want to access the color based on eyecolor of animal.

Comment: If you are indeed able to access name using `item.attributes.name`, you can use `item.attributes.testType` to access `testType`.

Comment: yes I can do so, but I want where `item.attributes.name` equals current selected record. how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function like this

```
String colorByEyeColor(String eyeColor, List list) {
  return animals.map((m) => m['attributes']).firstWhere((m) => m['eyecolor'] == eyeColor, orElse: () => {})['color'];
}
```

and use it:

```
print('${colorByEyeColor('red', animals)}'); // white
print('${colorByEyeColor('transparent', animals)}'); // null
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, but I need the color based on eyecolor and not animal name. can you add the answer for that?

Answer (score 1):

```dart
List animals = [{'name': 'horse', 'color': 'black'}, {'name': 'dog', 'color': 'white'}];

String horseColor = animals.where((animal) => animal['name'] == 'horse').first['name'];

print(horseColor);
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers works for me. but as I could see my list is little different then what I posted, I have updated the question - can you take a look?